# C++ set iterator error: no match for ‘operator+=’

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate over a set of objects and create a comma-separated string of their names. The commented-out part of the code is supposed to add a comma only if it is not the last one in the set, but it generates the following error:

error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator’ and ‘long int’)
  _M_current += -__n;

It works fine if I use a vector instead of a set. What am I doing wrong?

```
std::string paramList = "";
std::set<Param>::iterator end = params.end();
for (std::set<Param>::iterator it = params.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
  paramList += (*it).name;
  /*if (it != end -1) {
    paramList += ",";
  }*/
}
```

Comment: Your C++ book should have an explanation, in detail, of the differences between input iterators, output iterators, forward iterators, bidirectional iterators, and random access iterators; and what you can do with which type of an iterator, and which containers use what kind of iterators.

Comment: `works fine if I use a vector instead of a list.`: I don't see any vector or list. I thought this was about `std::set`? Is the commented-out code the one causing the error?

Comment: this works with c++94 too: before appending `(*it).name`, just `if (it!=params.begin()) {paramList += ",";}`

Comment: Never heard of C++94.

Comment: ops... c++98 :)

Comment: Side note: [Range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It may be simpler and faster to just remove the extra character afterwards.

Comment: @user10605163 I meant set, not list, updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only certain categories of iterator allow you to directly perform arbitrary arithmetic, like `end-1`.

The iterator of a set permits going forwards and backwards one step at a time, using `it++` and `it--`. It is true that `it - 1` still only traverses one step, but the rule is more general (the language doesn't know that the integer you're providing is just `1` and has no reason to make a special case compared to, say, `42`).

It is possible to use `std::next`/`std::prev` to get this behaviour. This is deliberately more verbose, in order to discourage you from arbitrary arithmetic on the iterator, which is more costly for this kind of iterator than it would be for a simple array-like thing such as a vector.

In this case, `std::prev(end)` will work for you, and be reasonably idiomatic.

But, if you find yourself writing something like `std::next(it, 42)`, you probably want to consider improving your algorithm, or using a different container.

Again, the purpose of this restriction is to encourage exactly that thinking.

Another way to write your algorithm might be:

```
std::string paramList;
std::set<Param>::iterator begin = params.begin(), end = params.end();
for (std::set<Param>::iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
  if (it != begin)
    paramList += ",";

  paramList += (*it).name;
}
```

Notice how I've flipped the logic to avoid the need to do any arithmetic at all.

I actually usually use a `bool` flag for this (when my `paramList` is a stringstream) or just always append a `,` then shrink `paramList` by one later (when it's a string) if `params` was non-empty.

Comment: Do you mean std::prev?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the well thought out answer. It works!

Comment: @tmath Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

```
end -1
```

This part is causing the problem. `std::set` only has [Bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), so it only accepts `operator ++` and `operator --` on it.

You should use [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) form `<iterator>` header instead:

```
if (it != std::prev(end))
```