# C++ set iterator error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in set

Tags: c++, set

```
auto str=lower_bound(s.begin(),s.end(),n);


cout<<std::distance(s.begin()+1,str)+1;
```

Why `+1` not working after `s.begin()`? It shows that there is no match for `operator+` (operand types are 'std::set::iterator'...)

Comment: Then what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: `set`s are typically implemented with a tree structure, and the + and += operators don't make much sense for a tree since they lack random access. To find the item at +2, you have to find +1. To keep people from making bad assumptions that result in poor code performance, C++ doesn't fake random access and hide sequential access behind a + or += operator.

Comment: Related: [C++ set iterator error: no match for ‘operator+=’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725453/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::set` iterators are [bi-directional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) iterators, which are required only to implement the `--` and `++` operators. [Random-access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) iterators implement `+`/`-` and `+=`/`-=` operators.

You can use [`std::advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) or [`std::next()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to move an iterator forward when it doesn't implement `operator+`, eg:

```cpp
auto str = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), n);
auto iter = s.begin();
std::advance(iter, 1);
cout << std::distance(iter, str) + 1;
```

```cpp
auto str = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), n);
cout << std::distance(std::next(s.begin()), str) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `std::set::iterator` does not support `operator+` (it's a [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) supporting `operator--` and `operator++`), so it fails here:

```
s.begin() + 1
```

Skip `+1` and it'll work, but it'll not be a single operation. I'll have to step forward from `s.begin()` to `str` in order to calculate the distance:

```
std::cout << std::distance(s.begin(), str);
```

Note: In order to get the same result as `std::distance(s.begin() + 1, str) + 1;` would have given if it had worked, you must skip the `+1` you have after `std::distance()` too.